# How can I link from a printed textbook to online exercises apart from QR codes?

Tags: print-design

We're writing a print textbook that will have online interactive exercises, which we want the students to be able quickly access. We could use QR codes, but they're ugly. Is there a better solution, or is there a way to make the QR codes look not so bad?

Comment: People under 18 think QR codes are de rigueur. Everybody has a phone that can read them The 'old' folks seem to prefer to manually type out dubya-dubya-dubya-dot-alongname-dot-com-slash-reference. I'm not sure what 3rd alternative you would like.

Comment: @Tetsujin depends where you are in china and japan sure. In europe not nearly as much. Anyway there is a 3rd-6th alternative make your books desemination site easy to use. Then you dont need but one link or even just goigle book name easy peasy. Make a book app. Develop a new 2D memory. Use RFID.

Comment: what about using a bitly address maybe?

Comment: @joojaa Unfortunately, we have very little control over CUP's website, but we have some control over how the sends people there.

Comment: @Brett well you are a designer you should ne able to atleast talk about that. Great design is doing things better after all. But yeah you can customize qr codes

Comment: @joojaa, I'm an author, not a designer.

Comment: Even more reason for you to make the webpage.

Comment: You really only have 3 choices... a QR code, the url, or both. If the URL is too complex to be effective. You *could* simply buy another domain and set up a *forwarder*.

Comment: Another alternative: A single web page with chapter by chapter headings, and under each head, links to the content for that chapter. Then, at least, the user/reader has to remember/bookmark only one URL rather than one for each bit of content. If you want to get fancy, you can add #bookmarks to each chapter heading and let the readers know that they can shortcut by appending #Chapter1 etc. to the end of your URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the visual code generators out there.
just a quick google search found this free(ish) one, but there are tons of others:
[Visual QR Code Generator](https://www.visualead.com/)

Although I would highly recommend going with the paid version if you use this particular one.

[image: test code]